# missing some text when iterating xml elements in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am running the following code in Python 2.7.3 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

```python
import StringIO
from lxml import etree
f = open('./foo', 'r')
doc = ""
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    doc += line
    if line == "":
        break
tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(doc), etree.HTMLParser())
r = tree.xpath('//foo')
for i in r:
    for j in i.iter():
        print j.tag, j.text
```

And the file foo contains

```
<foo> AAA <bar> BBB </bar> XXX </foo>
```

The output is

```
foo AAA
bar BBB
```

Why am I not getting the text `XXX`?  How do I access it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring("<foo> AAA <bar> BBB </bar> XXX </foo>")
foos = tree.xpath('//foo')

for foo in foos:
    for j in foo.iter():
        print j.tag, j.text, j.tail
```

Output:

```
foo  AAA  None
bar  BBB   XXX
```

The [`tail`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail) attribute holds the text after the end tag of the element.

`tail` is a peculiarity of lxml and ElementTree compared to other XML models, such as DOM. See http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/etree-view.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks!  That's an interesting quirk I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 6):

You also have to take

```
node.tail
```

into account (or check for it).