# Search keyword between <p> tags separated by <ref> tags

Tags: python, xml, lxml, tei

I want to search keyword in the following xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0 /home/pisenberg/grobid/grobid-0.6.1/grobid-home/schemas/xsd/Grobid.xsd"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <text xml:lang="en">
            <body>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><p>text before ref<ref type="bibr" target="#b18">[19,</ref><ref type="bibr" target="#b46">47,</ref><ref type="bibr" target="#b66">67]</ref>text after ref</p></div>
            </body>
        </text>
</TEI>
```

My code:

```python
from lxml import etree
import os
import csv
from shutil import copyfile
import pandas as pd

teins = {'tei':'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0'} #info on the xml structure

searchterm = "before" #put your search term in lowercase

filepath = "./test.xml"
        
            
with open(filepath,'r', encoding='utf8') as file:  
    try:
        tree = etree.parse(file)
        root = etree.XML(etree.tostring(tree))
        textNode = root.find(".//tei:text",teins)
        for elem in textNode.iter():
            if elem.text:
                if searchterm.lower() in elem.text.lower():
                    print(elem.text)
                
    except Exception as e: # work on python 3.x
                print(str(e))
```

if I search "before", I can get result, it prints "before". However, if I search "after", it will print nothing.

I feel `textNode.iter()` cannot reach the text within `<p>` tags after `<ref>` tags.
I was wondering anyone knows how to solve this?

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: what is the info that you want to get from the XML?

Comment: What you need to take into account is that "text after ref" is the `tail` of the last `<ref>` element. This is a common stumbling block with lxml and ElementTree. There have been many questions related to this, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/65506059/407651. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12412264/407651.

Comment: @balderman I want to search for keyword. If there is such keywords, then print it. For example, if  `searchterm = "before"`, it will print `before`

Comment: @mzjn thanks a lot, I will check it.